# Laravel 4 Preview Form Submit

Tags: forms, laravel, preview

Any idea how to solve the following approach.
I have a form and want to display the entered data in a specific formtemplate before store it in the DB. If the entered data looks properly, the user can save the form.So I am searching for a way to display the entered data as a preview in a new window/tab first. With my code below I am not able to preview the form without saving the data in the databse. Also display the preview in a new window or tab is not possible. I guess there is no way to achieve this with php / laravel. I tried some onlick events, but no luck. As it seems like the route is prefered. 
Any idea how to solve this?

My form looks like:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'backend/menubuilder/'.$id, 'method' => 'PUT'))}}

<section>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h3>Montag</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{Form::label('gericht_1_mo','Gericht 1')}}
          {{Form::textarea('gericht_1_mo', Auth::user()->gericht_1_mo,array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{Form::label('preis_1_mo','Preis', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))}}
          {{Form::text('preis_1_mo', Auth::user()->preis_1_mo, array('class' => 'col-md-6'))}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mrgT55">
          {{Form::label('gericht_2_mo','Gericht 2')}}
          {{Form::textarea('gericht_2_mo', Auth::user()->gericht_2_mo,array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{Form::label('preis_2_mo','Preis', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))}}
          {{Form::text('preis_2_mo', Auth::user()->preis_2_mo, array('class' => 'col-md-6'))}}
        </div>
      </div>                   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{Form::submit('update')}}
{{-- <input type="submit" name="preview" value="preview"> --}}
{{Form::close()}}
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'backend/menubuilder/templatesview/'.$id, 'method' => 'POST'))}}
{{-- {{Form::submit('Preview',array('onClick' => 'target_blank'))}} --}}
<input onclick="newTab()" type="submit" name="preview" value="preview" >
{{Form::close()}}
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('backend/menubuilder/templates/{id}', 'MenuBuilderController@template');
Route::post('backend/menubuilder/templatesview/{id}', 'MenuBuilderController@preview');
```

My Controller:

```
    public function preview($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $owner = (Auth::id() === (int) $id);
    return View::make('backend/menubuilder/templatesview/tempone')->withUser($user)->withOwner($owner); 
}

public function template($id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    $owner = (Auth::id() === (int) $id);
    return View::make('backend/menubuilder/templates/tempone')->withUser($user)->withOwner($owner);     
}
```

Comment: If the preview is handled on a separate page (no AJAX) and a confirmation of the preview is the action that should store the data to the database, then it should be pretty easy to handle. Just post the form where you're making the changes to `MenuBuilderController@preview`, so that way the preview gets the data that should of had been stored in the database and can use it to display the actual preview.

Comment: And if you want to post the form to a new tab just add `target="_blank"` to your form attributes.